# How To bind data using TypeScript Controller & Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am Playing around with Type Script.I have convert my angular js controller to Type Script But i m facing problem in ng-repeater. (I have attached my controller code below:-

```
class CustomCtrl{
    public customer;
    public ticket;
    public services;
    public cust_File;
    public ticket_file;
    public service_file;

    static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache'];
    constructor (
            private $http,
            private $templateCache
    ){}
```

Comment: So, I checked/fixed plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/3XORgParE2v9d0OVg515?p=preview and it should work and show that all in action.. hope it helps

Comment: Great Help!!!! Thanksssss @RadimKöhler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to add another answer describing more details how to create and use  controller in **`TypeScript`** and inject it into **`angularJS`**.

This is extension of this Answer

[How can I define my controller using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30506888/1679310) Where we also have [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3XORgParE2v9d0OVg515?p=preview)

So having this directive:

```
export class CustomerSearchDirective implements ng.IDirective
{
    public restrict: string = "E";
    public replace: boolean = true;
    public template: string = "<div>" +
        "<input ng-model=\"SearchedValue\" />" +
        "<button ng-click=\"Ctrl.Search()\" >Search</button>" +
        "<p> for searched value <b>{{SearchedValue}}</b> " +
        " we found: <i>{{FoundResult}}</i></p>" +
        "</div>";
    public controller: string = 'CustomerSearchCtrl';
    public controllerAs: string = 'Ctrl';
    public scope = {};
}
```

We can see, that we declared this directive to be available as **E**lement. We also in-lined a **template**. This template is ready to bind **`SearchedValue`** and call Action on our controller **`Ctrl.Search()`**. We are saying what is the name of controller: 'CustomerSearchCtrl' and asking runtime to make it available as 'Ctrl' *(conrollerAs:)*

Finally we inject that object into angular module:

```
app.directive("customerSearch", [() => new CustomerSearch.CustomerSearchDirective()]);
```

We can use `$scope` as `ng.IScope`, but to have more typed access to it, we can create our own *interface*:

```
export interface ICustomerSearchScope  extends ng.IScope
{
    SearchedValue: string;
    FoundResult: string;
    Ctrl: CustomerSearchCtrl;
}
```

This way, we know, that we have string `SearchedValue` and also other string `FoundResult`. We also informed the application that Ctrl will be injected into that scope, and will be of type `CustomerSearchCtrl`. And here comes that controller:

```
export class CustomerSearchCtrl
{
    static $inject = ["$scope", "$http"];
    constructor(protected $scope: CustomerSearch.ICustomerSearchScope,
        protected $http: ng.IHttpService)
    {
        // todo
    }
    public Search(): void
    {
        this.$http
            .get("data.json")
            .then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>) =>
            {
                var data = response.data;
                this.$scope.FoundResult = data[this.$scope.SearchedValue]
                    || data["Default"];
            });
    }
}
```

plus its registration into module

```
app.controller('CustomerSearchCtrl',  CustomerSearch.CustomerSearchCtrl);
```

What is interesting on this controller? it has one public acton Search, which has access to all its membes via `this.`, e.g. `this.$http`. Because we instructed intellisense in VS that angular.d.ts type/interface

```
protected $http: ng.IHttpService
```

will be used, we can later easily access its methods. Similar is the type of returned value in `.then()`

```
.then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>) => {...
```

which does contain data: {} of any type...

Hope it helps a bit, observe that all in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3XORgParE2v9d0OVg515?p=preview)

Comment: If that helped... great. Enjoy amazing combination of TypeScript and AngularJS (and version 2.0 will be even better;)

Comment: Kohler getting status as 400

Comment: Rise new question, would be my suggestion. It does not make sense to extend these, already solved. You will get larger audience... and higher probability to get answer..

Comment: Please Review Question Getting Error in Angular js + Type Script in http put status 400

Answer (score 2):

There is one issue with your constructor and `$inject` - these must fit together

```
// wrong
static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache'];
constructor (
        private $http,
        private $templateCache
){}

// should be
static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache'];
constructor (
        private $scope,
        private $http,
        private $templateCache
){}
```

> What happened in fact - all params were moved in the meaning, that `$http` was `$scope` in fact, etc...

Simply, **`$inject`** array MUST fit to constructor parameter list

BTW, that's why I had previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30482388/1679310 suggested to use types in the declaration:

```
   constructor(protected $scope: ICustomerScope,
        protected $http: ng.IHttpService,
        protected $templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService)
    { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for good suggestion but Done with that too still same problem.

Comment: What is the error you are provided with? could you place it in the question?

Comment: Kohler I have created two sepearte file one as my controller and second the module code provided by you but it's giving me error of ng is not found i have attached a jpeg with my question

Comment: You'd need d.ts file with angular stuff. The latest could be found here https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts, Also read this to get more details how these files do work http://definitelytyped.org/

Comment: Kohelr where i have to add this below code:-
var app = angular.module("MyControllerModule");    

    app.controller("CustomerCtrl", MyModule.CustomerCtrl);
}

Comment: These should go at the top of the file like `/// <reference path="../../../Scripts/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />`... Visual studio will then be happy

Answer (score 0):

The library [Bindable TS](https://github.com/errisy/bindable/blob/master/README.md) is an alternative way to set up data binding with typescript.

Answer (score -1):

From quick review of your code I have found that `search` method of controller is private. May be changing it to public will solve problem.

Comment: Nups Problem Remains Same