# Scope of Controller in Directive using Typescript on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript

I am continuing my quest to learn Typescript and AngularJS and had a question on scope. I am working on a project, where each person in the project is responsible for a directive. However I recently hit a road block in my understanding.

Currently I have an html page that has the following

```
<html ng-app ="helloworld">
    <head>
        <!--insert scripts here-->
    </head>
    <body>
       <direct-a></direct-a>
       <hello-world></hello-world>
    </body>
</html>
```

We have set the directive to be something along the lines of this:

```js
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
module helloWorld{

var app :angular.IModule = angular.module('helloWorld');

app.directive('helloWorld', HelloWorldDirective);

    function HelloWorldDirective() :ng.IDirective{

        return <ng.IDirective>{
            controller: 'HelloWorldController',
            controllerAs : 'vm',
            templateUrl: './app/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.html'          

        };

};

}
```

I had similar code to this on the `<direct-a>` directive, but with the code, I was unable to see anything from the `<hello-world>` tag, until we changed `controllerAs` to something other than 'vm'. Which leads me to wonder if we need to devise naming conventions for our custom directives, and not use the 'vm' phrase for `controllerAs`? Or is there a trick I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created two examples:

- there [is BROKEN plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkqLAiMVDjMOyU6oeQGV?p=preview)
- there [is fully WORKING plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kKuGEOOPTFokqgPb6rgR?p=preview)

#### BROKEN

This is the way how I created **`<hello-world>`** directive *(related to this [How can I define my controller using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30482138/1679310))*

```
module HelloWorld
{
    var app = angular.module('TheApp');
    
    export class HelloWorldDirective implements ng.IDirective
    {
        public restrict: string = "E";
        public replace: boolean = true;
        public template: string = "<div>" +
            "<input ng-model=\"vm.MyValue\" />" +
            "<button ng-click=\"vm.Show()\" >Show my value</button>" +
            "<p> my value <b>{{vm.MyValue}}</b></p>" +
            "</div>";
        public controller: string = 'HelloWorldCtrl';
        public controllerAs: string = 'vm';
        //public scope = {};
    }    
    app.directive("helloWorld", [() => new HelloWorld.HelloWorldDirective()]);

    export interface IHelloWorldScope  extends ng.IScope
    {
        // properties for isolated scope
    }
    export class HelloWorldCtrl
    {
        static $inject = ["$scope"];
        constructor(protected $scope: HelloWorld.IHelloWorldScope){ }
        public MyValue: string = "InitValue";
        public Show(): void
        {
            alert(this.MyValue)
        }
    }
    app.controller('HelloWorldCtrl',  HelloWorld.HelloWorldCtrl);
}
```

And this is **`<other-directive>`** TypeScript code:

```
module OtherDirective
{
    var app = angular.module('TheApp');
    
    export class OtherDirectiveDirective implements ng.IDirective
    {
        public restrict: string = "E";
        public replace: boolean = true;
        public template: string = "<h4>" +
            "OtherValue: {{vm.OtherValue}}" +
            "</h4>";
        public controller: string = 'OtherDirectiveCtrl';
        public controllerAs: string = 'vm';
        //public scope = {};
    }

    app.directive("otherDirective", [() => new OtherDirective.OtherDirectiveDirective()]);

    export interface IOtherDirectiveScope  extends ng.IScope
    {
      // properties for isolated scope
    }
    export class OtherDirectiveCtrl
    {
        static $inject = ["$scope"];
        constructor(protected $scope: OtherDirective.IOtherDirectiveScope) {}
        public OtherValue: string = "This is other Value";
    }
    app.controller('OtherDirectiveCtrl',  OtherDirective.OtherDirectiveCtrl);
}
```

So, if we would place these two side by side:

```
<div>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
    <other-directive></other-directive>
</div>
```

The **`<hello-world>`** won't work. It will be broken. The reason is *"shared"*, **not isolated scope**, which both directives access.

#### make it WORKING

To fix it, we have to change both *(at least one in this simple example)*. *Or use different names for `controllerAs`*.

check the doc ([Angular Directive Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive))

> #### Isolating the Scope of a Directive
>
> Our myCustomer directive above is great, but it has a fatal flaw. We can only use it once within a given scope.
> ...
> What we want to be able to do is separate the scope inside a directive from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's inner scope. We can do this by creating what we call an isolate scope. To do this, we can use a directive's scope option:

Here we will ask for **isolated scope**:

```
export class HelloWorldDirective implements ng.IDirective
{
    public restrict: string = "E";
    public replace: boolean = true;
    public template: string = "<div>" +
        "<input ng-model=\"vm.MyValue\" />" +
        "<button ng-click=\"vm.Show()\" >Show my value</button>" +
        "<p> my value <b>{{vm.MyValue}}</b></p>" +
        "</div>";
    public controller: string = 'HelloWorldCtrl';
    public controllerAs: string = 'vm';
    // isolated scope requested
    public scope = {};
}

export class OtherDirectiveDirective implements ng.IDirective
{
    public restrict: string = "E";
    public replace: boolean = true;
    public template: string = "<h4>" +
        "OtherValue: {{vm.OtherValue}}" +
        "</h4>";
    public controller: string = 'OtherDirectiveCtrl';
    public controllerAs: string = 'vm';
    // isolated scope requested as well
    public scope = {};
}
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkqLAiMVDjMOyU6oeQGV?p=preview)
More about this approach:

- [How can I define my controller using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30482138/1679310)
- [How To bind data using TypeScript Controller & Angular Js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30501735/1679310)

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;)

Comment: it was a great help :)