# Best way to expose angularjs controller methods when using typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I understand one way of doing it is attaching the controller object to the scope like below.

```
interface IAppCtrlScope extends ng.IScope {
   info: any;
}

class InfoCtrl {
    header: string;
    name: string;

    public static $inject = ["$scope"];
    constructor(private $scope: IAppCtrlScope) {        
       this.$scope.info= this; //expose controller
    }

    getData(): void {
      //do something
    }    
}
```

In this case the view will be something like this,

```
<div ng-controller="InfoCtrl">
    <div class="rm-dialog-header">{{info.header}}</div>
    <span ng-click="info.getData()">{{info.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Instead of the above is there a way to expose the controllers so that I dont have to prefix each scope variable with 'info.'. So that the view will be like this,

```
<div ng-controller="InfoCtrl">
    <div class="rm-dialog-header">{{header}}</div>
    <span ng-click="getData()">{{name}}</span>
</div>
```

Is it possible or am I missing something?

Comment: *Before you'll get your answer, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30506888/1679310) is how I use it with a working plunker*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose methods from your class directly on the $scope

```
interface IAppCtrlScope extends ng.IScope {
   getData: () => void;
}

class InfoCtrl {
    header: string;
    name: string;

    public static $inject = ["$scope"];
    constructor(private $scope: IAppCtrlScope) {        
       $scope.getData = this.getData; //expose method
    }

    getData = () => {
      //do something
    }    
}
```

then in you markup you can bind directly to `getData()`

Just make sure you declare your method using the syntax `method = () => {}`, this places the method on the instance rather than the prototype.

Comment: Please read [Y030](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y030) onwards in the Angular style guide and use `controller as` instead. `$scope` is really a deprecated concepts now, especially if you want to migrate to Angular 2 in the future.