# Writing an Angular directive with a TypeScript class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

I may just be attempting to combine too many "new-to-me" concepts at once, but I am trying to write a custom Angular directive using a TypeScript class. At the moment, I'm not trying to do anything terribly useful, just a POC.

I have a TypeScript file that looks like this:

```
module App {
    'use strict';

    export class appStepper {

        public link:(scope:angular.IScope, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes) => void;
        public template:string = '<div>0</div><button>-</button><button>+</button>';
        public scope = {};
        public restrict:string = 'EA';

        constructor(){ }

        public static Factory(){
            var directive = () =>
            { return new appStepper(); };
            return directive;
        }
    }

    angular.module('app').directive('appStepper', App.appStepper.Factory());
}
```

It compiles to this in JavaScript:

```
(function(App) {
    'use strict';
    var appStepper = (function() {
        function appStepper() {
            this.template = '<div>0</div><button>-</button><button>+</button>';
            this.scope = {};
            this.restrict = 'EA';
        }
        appStepper.Factory = function() {
            var directive = function() {
                return new appStepper();
            };
            return directive;
        };
        return appStepper;
    })();
    App.appStepper = appStepper;
    angular.module('app').directive('appStepper', App.appStepper.Factory());
})(App || (App = {}));
```

My angular module looks like (I don't even know if I need to do this):

```
angular.module('app',['appStepper'])
```

And I attempt to use it in my view:

```
<div app-stepper></div>
```

And get these errors:

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] 
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Why doesn't my `app` know about my directive?

Comment: It should be `angular.module('app', [])`.

Comment: Good to know! But it still leaves me with the same problem.

Comment: Check this, with detailed explanation and working plunker http://stackoverflow.com/a/30506888/1679310

Comment: @RadimKöhler - after following that example, I found success! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though it is not quite the same question, this answer included an example of what I'm attempting to do: [How can I define my controller using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482138/how-can-i-define-my-controller-using-typescript/30506888#30506888)

I followed the example in the Plnkr it referenced and found success: http://plnkr.co/edit/3XORgParE2v9d0OVg515?p=preview

My final TypeScript directive looks like:

```
module App {
    'use strict';

    export class appStepper implements angular.IDirective {

        public link:(scope:angular.IScope, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes) => void;
        public template:string = '<div>0</div><button>-</button><button>+</button>';
        public scope = {};
        public restrict:string = 'EA';

        constructor(){ }

    }

    angular.module('app').directive('appStepper', [() => new App.appStepper()]);
}
```