# Writing complex AngularJS directive in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

I've found the following directive to select objects from checkboxes:

https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

My problem is that we are using typescript and i have absolutely no idea how to write the given directive in typescript.

I know that the basic style is the following

```
module myModule {
    'use strict';
    export function checklistModel(): ng.IDirective {
        return {...};
   };
};
```

My problem is that I need the $parse and $compile services to get injected. I've tried to put the code from the directive in the link but I have no idea how to get the directive working.

Could someone please give me a hint on how to inject services and which part of the given code goes in the link and/or the compile?

Comment: *Try to check this: [Writing an Angular directive with a TypeScript class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30673363/1679310)*

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific issue with TypeScript regarding dependency injection. Simply define the dependencies you want to inject as parameters of `checklistModel`. If you want to ensure that the dependencies can be resolved after a minification of the javascript files, you can define the dependencies additionally via the `$inject` property (This will work in normal js as well):

```
module myModule {
'use strict';

    checklistModel.$inject = ['$parse', '$compile'];

    export function checklistModel($parse, $compile): ng.IDirective {
        return {
             link: function() { ... }
        };
   };

   angular.module('myModule').directive('checklistModel', checklistModel);
};
```

Everything else is normal angular stuff. (Beside that, the type IDirective will tell you how the return-value should look like)

I hope this will help.