# Not a function error with common scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have the following code as my controller...

```
module scrumtool.app.Controllers {
    export class ConfigController implements Directives.IConfigScope{
        static $inject = [
            "$scope"
        ];
        public message: string = "Testing";
        constructor() { }

        clickMe = () => {
            return this.message;
        }
    }
}
```

The `IConfigScope` *interface* is defined as such under the *directives* module for the time being...

```
export interface IConfigScope {
    message: string;
    clickMe(): string;
}
```

The *directive* is then like so...

```
module scrumtool.app.Directives {
    export interface IConfigScope {
        message: string;
        clickMe(): string;
    }
    export class Cog implements ng.IDirective {
        restrict: string = "A";
        controller = Controllers.ConfigController;
        constructor($scope: Directives.IConfigScope) {

        }
        link = function($scope: Directives.IConfigScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, 
                        attr: ng.IAttributes, ctrl: Controllers.ConfigController) {
            element.on("click", (e) => {
                alert(ctrl.clickMe());
            });
        }

        static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            var directive: ng.IDirectiveFactory =
                ($scope: Directives.IConfigScope) => new Cog($scope);

            directive.$inject = [];

            return directive;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially I was able to make this work. What I don't understand is that through the `$scope` variable I can access the **`message`** variable and have it alert the message "Testing".

What I can't quite understand is why I can't simply say:

```
alert($scope.clickMe());
```

and have it return the message. When I attempt the above I get undefined.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependencies defined inside of the:

```
static $inject = [
        "$scope"
    ];
```

must be somehow delivered, injected. The way with angular is via **`constructor`**. So we need this:

```
// there is no param in constructor, to be used
// constructor() { }
// but we need one - $scope
constructor(protected $scope) { }
```

we also should provide a type of passed $scope

```
constructor(protected $scope:IConfigScope) { }
```

which will mean, that the passed `$scope` would have these `messages` and `clickMe` implemented.

Other words - **controller won't implement `IConfigScope`**, it will be provided with that

But if we want to let our controller do that job, we should use controllerAs syntax

```
export class Cog implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict: string = "A";
    controller = Controllers.ConfigController;
    controllerAs = "Ctrl";
    ...
```

and later anywhere inside of view template we can use

```
 {{Ctrl.messages}}
 ...
 ng-click="Ctrl.clickMe()"
```

Comment: Beg your pardon, but could you perhaps re-write the code I have provided implementing your suggestions so that I may get a complete understanding? I have also seen others avoid using ng-controller and instead just use the directive attaching a controller to it and using it internally. Is this possible?

Comment: I am a bit in a hurry, there is a link to an example (and other links) http://stackoverflow.com/q/30673363/1679310 ... if it won't help I will try to get to you later... http://stackoverflow.com/q/30482138/1679310

Comment: And here http://stackoverflow.com/q/30501735/1679310 (all the links have more details PLUS working example! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for not being a dick and being helpful instead. Very much appreciated.

Comment: If that helped anyhow - great! ;) Enjoy Typescript with AngularJS, sir