# Create AngularJs controller using TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have JS code with Angular controller which starts like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('BookmarksController', function($scope, bookmarkService, crawlerService) {
```

I want to rewrite it using TypeScript.  Here is my code:

```
class Some {

    constructor($scope, bookmarkService, crawlerService) {} 
}

angular
    .module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('BookmarksController', Some($scope, bookmarkService, crawlerService));
```

It doesn't work:

> Can not find name $scope, bookmarkService, crawlerService

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way *(well, solution ready for minification)* would be:

```
class Some {
    // instruction for IoC
    static $inject = ["$scope", "bookmarkService", "crawlerService"];

    constructor($scope, bookmarkService, crawlerService) {} 
}

angular
    .module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('BookmarksController', Some);
```

Where we are using the **`static $inject = []`** array for IoC names, which will work even after minification. Then we just register the controller class

```
.controller('BookmarksController', Some);
```

and later angular IoC will properly find out what should be injected as constructor params

In case we would use some modules/namespaces

```
module My.Namespace
{
    class Some {
```

we would use:

```
.controller('BookmarksController', My.Namespace.Some);
```

Comment: There is even a Q & A: [How can I define my controller using TypeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30482138/1679310) with some working plunker and other links with other details and examples