# Error in directive implementation of regex test as attribute - validations (typescript + angular)

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, typescript

I'm trying to build a module that has directive for custom validations.

The validations are done via regex.

The error I am seeing is:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: REG_EXPProvider <- REG_EXP <- uniIdValidatorDirective

My code looks like this:

config.ts:

```
module LoginModule {

    'use strict';

    /***** REGEX *****/
    export class regExp {
        public ID_OR_PASSPORT = /^[0-9]{9}$/;
        public USERNAME_SINGLE_WORD = /^[A-Za-z0-9à-ú-_\.]{6,8}$/;
        public PASSWORD = /^[A-Za-z0-9à-ú-_\.]{8}$/;
        public EMAIL = /^([\?!\/]*)+\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
        public ALPHANUMERIC = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
        public NUM = /^[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,}$/;
        public PHONE_BODY = /^[0-9]{7}$/;
    };
    angular.module("LoginModule").value('REG_EXP', regExp);
}
```

Validation directive:

```
module LoginModule {
    uniIdValidator.$inject = ['REG_EXP'];
    angular.module('LoginModule').directive('uniIdValidator', uniIdValidator);
    export function uniIdValidator(REG_EXP): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: ['ngModel'],
            templateUrl: 'errorMessages.html',
            replace: true,
            link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, 
                   attrs: ng.IAttributes, ctrls:any) => {
                ctrls.$validators.userId = function (modelValue) {
                    return REG_EXP.ID_OR_PASSPORT.test(modelValue);
                };
            }
        }
    };
}
```

In my html:

```
<Input ... uni-id-validator />
```

added my app.ts:

```
((): void=> {
    var appLogin = angular.module("LoginModule", ['ngRoute', 'ngMessages']);
    appLogin.config(LoginModule.Routes.configureRoutes);
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QWOxMyW0oJJhyapjl3Dr?p=preview) *(showing that the below approach is able to create working directive with simplified REG_EXP implementation)*

The way I do create directives with Typescript is similar to this:

```
module LoginModule {
    //uniIdValidator.$inject = ['REG_EXP'];
    //angular.module('LoginModule').directive('uniIdValidator', uniIdValidator);
    export class uniIdValidator implements ng.IDirective 
    {
        constructor(public REG_EXP) {}
        public restrict: string = 'A';
        public require: string = 'ngModel';
        public templateUrl: string = 'errorMessages.html';
        public replace: boolean = true;
        public link: Function = (scope: ng.IScope, 
            element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery,
            attrs: ng.IAttributes, 
            ctrls:any) => 
            {
                ctrls.$validators.userId = function (modelValue) 
                {
                    //return REG_EXP.ID_OR_PASSPORT.test(modelValue);
                    return "TO DO";
                };
            }          
    }

    angular.module('LoginModule')
      .directive('uniIdValidator', ['REG_EXP', 
          (REG_EXP) =>  {return new LoginModule.uniIdValidator(REG_EXP) });
}
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QWOxMyW0oJJhyapjl3Dr?p=preview). [Here is a link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=module%20LoginModule%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20'use%20strict'%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*****%20REGEX%20*****%2F%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20regExp%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20ID_OR_PASSPORT%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B9%7D%24%2F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20USERNAME_SINGLE_WORD%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9%C3%A0-%C3%BA-_%5C.%5D%7B6%2C8%7D%24%2F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20PASSWORD%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9%C3%A0-%C3%BA-_%5C.%5D%7B8%7D%24%2F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20EMAIL%20%3D%20%2F%5E(%5B%5C%3F!%5C%2F%5D*)%2B%5Cw%2B(%5B-%2B.%5D%5Cw%2B)*%40%5Cw%2B(%5B-.%5D%5Cw%2B)*%5C.%5Cw%2B(%5B-.%5D%5Cw%2B)*%24%2F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20ALPHANUMERIC%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%24%2F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20NUM%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%5B.%5D%7B0%2C1%7D%5B0-9%5D%7B0%2C%7D%24%2F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20PHONE_BODY%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B7%7D%24%2F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%0A%20%20%20%20angular.module(%22LoginModule%22).value('REG_EXP'%2C%20LoginModule.regExp)%3B%0A%7D%0A%20%20%0Amodule%20LoginModule%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2FuniIdValidator.%24inject%20%3D%20%5B'REG_EXP'%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fangular.module('LoginModule').directive('uniIdValidator'%2C%20uniIdValidator)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20uniIdValidator%20implements%20ng.IDirective%20%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09constructor(public%20REG_EXP)%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20restrict%3A%20string%20%3D%20'A'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20require%3A%20string%20%3D%20'ngModel'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20templateUrl%3A%20string%20%3D%20'errorMessages.html'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20replace%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20link%3A%20Function%20%3D%20(scope%3A%20ng.IScope%2C%20%0A%09%09%09element%3A%20ng.IAugmentedJQuery%2C%0A%09%09%09attrs%3A%20ng.IAttributes%2C%20%0A%09%09%09ctrls%3Aany)%20%3D%3E%20%0A%09%09%09%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ctrls.%24validators.userId%20%3D%20function%20(modelValue)%20%0A%09%09%09%09%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Freturn%20REG_EXP.ID_OR_PASSPORT.test(modelValue)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22TO%20DO%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09angular.module('LoginModule')%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.directive('uniIdValidator'%2C%20%5B'REG_EXP'%2C%20%0A%09%09%20%20(REG_EXP)%20%3D%3E%20%20%7Breturn%20new%20LoginModule.uniIdValidator(REG_EXP)%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D) to place which was used to transpile the TS to JS.

Some [other link to Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30482138/1679310) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32353071/1679310)) with working examples...

Comment: Thanks for this, can you alter your example to include the input field? I didn't understand how to use it :/

Comment: I had to comment out your `return REG_EXP.ID_OR_PASSPORT.test(modelValue)` because I am not sure about the overall concept of that stuff. Other words, not sure what that directive should do. So there is another plunker, with a version which does log to console what you type in: http://plnkr.co/edit/HIOCzsh0tPSGep9MBQY9?p=preview hope it helps a bit

Comment: The directive should display error message if the regex of that input will fail. (using ng-message). Trying out your new version now.

Comment: still not working :/ same error... are you missing "]" in the end of your before your last line?

Comment: My plunker is working. I used just `require = 'ngModel'` because it is enough, just one is required. if you use `require = ['ngModel'];` then `ctrls` argument passed into link function is array. That means that if you want to use validators of it, you need to call it like this `ctrls[0].$validators.`... hope it helps a bit. I am trying to help with Typescript and angular. What you are doing with validators is a bit out of scope of this Q & A... I'd say...

Comment: I copy & paste from the pluncer as is, and typescript is showing me error missing "," at the last line, I've added "]" instead, and it compiles, yet still I have the same error :/ frustrated.

Comment: Try this plunker with my latest version http://plnkr.co/edit/R67RBPK81rFBVcYGRQCp?p=preview ... typescript is 1 : 1 to javascript transpiled here http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Comment: Thanks, I have made a progress, you are missing a ']', the plucker just renders to a valid js, like mine. (if you can edit it, its better though), Now I have error that missing 'ngMessage', trying to figure out why. Tnx!

Comment: now can't get ngMessage to work... if you have the time to help out I will greatly appreciate it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421546/custom-validation-directive-using-ng-messages-and-typescript

Comment: *I tried to replicate your issue, but I cannot get your error message ;( If you could create some plunker... with this issue, I can assist... Or show more of your code and full exception... whatever could get me more info*

Comment: While trying to reproduce the error on plunker, I realized what the problem was: ng-message in the html template. (I tried to remove it before of course but it saved a cache file of my template before the change...)

Comment: Great, if that means you have solution! Great