# Attach method to controller using TypeScript and controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I've seen a couple of examples of using TypeScript with an angular controller and attaching methods via the scope [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482138/how-can-i-define-my-controller-using-typescript).

However, it's now better practice to use `controllerAs`.

Given the following TypeScript (assuming it was correctly registered as a controller elsewhere etc.):

```
class exampleCtrl {

    public publicArray = [1,2,3];

    public somePublicMethod() {
        window.console.log('ran function')
    }

}
```

This produces:

```
var exampleCtrl = (function () {
    function exampleCtrl() {
        this.publicArray = [1, 2, 3];
    }
    exampleCtrl.prototype.somePublicMethod = function () {
        window.console.log('ran function');
    };
    return exampleCtrl;
}());
```

Notice how `somePublicMethod` has been added to the *prototype*, yet `publicArray` is added directly to `this`.

As far as I can tell, methods added to the prototype are not available via the DOM using controllerAs.

e.g

```
<div ng-controller="exampleCtrl as vm">
    {{vm}} <!-- No function is output just {"publicArray":[1,2,3]} -->
    <div ng-click="vm.somePublicMethod">Click me</div> <!-- click event doesn't work -->
</div>
```

How can I now access `somePublicMethod` **via the DOM**?
Or rather, how can I make a public function in a TypeScript (ES6) class publicly accessible when using controllerAs syntax?

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1v4Sw22SOjUh5LktYA5H) to show what I am seeing.

---

Other points:

I know `public`, `private` and `protected` don't actually change the way the code is transpiled, it just warns you if you use it wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is

```
<div ng-click="vm.somePublicMethod()">Click me</div>
```

> As far as I can tell, methods added to the prototype are not available via the DOM using controllerAs.

They are. That's how JS prototypes work.

Comment: Oh whoops, simple error when making an isolated example. I thought that was the case. Worth knowing it's possible though. I guess there is a problem elsewhere in my app then. Thanks.